# How to declare an AngularJs service with no parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

This works:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp').service('searchControllerPersistentData', ['$state', function ($state) 
{
    const Self = this;
}]);
```

but this gives an error in the controller where I try to inject the service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp').service('searchControllerPersistentData', ['', function () 
{
    const Self = this;
}]);
```

The service will not need anything injected into it. How do I declare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the brackets :

```
angular.module('MyApp').service('searchControllerPersistentData', function () 
{
    const Self = this;
});
```

Comment: D'oh!  :-) Thanks for that